# JPQL Constructor execution takes long time

Tags: java, sql, jpa, jpql

I am using JPQL constructor in my code. It involves large results, 5024 data retrieved and objects created when executing this query. It is taking around 2 minutes to complete its execution. There are multiple tables involved to execute this query. I could not go for cache since the DB data will update daily. Is there any way to optimize the execution speed?

My SQL query formation is like this,

```
String sql = "SELECT DISTINCT "
                  + "new com.abc.dc.entity.market.LaptopData(vd.segment.id, vd.segment.segmentGroup, "
                  + "vd.segment.segmentName, vd.segment.category, "
                  + "vd.product.make, vd.product.model, vd.product.modelYear) "
                  + "FROM LaptopData vd, Profile p "
                  + "WHERE vd.profile.profileCode = :profileCode "
                  + "AND vd.pk.profileId = p.id "
                  + "Order By vd.segment.segmentGroup, vd.segment.segmentName, vd.product.make, vd.product.model,"
                  + " vd.product.modelYear asc";
Query query = em.createQuery(sql);
query.setParameter("profileCode", profileCode);

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<LaptopData> results = query.getResultList();

em.clear();
return results;
```

Comment: looked at the generated SQL that is executed? and where the time is spent?

Answer (score 0):

Well, one option for you is to create separate table which would contain result of this query for all entities and update it daily (every night) and then run your query on this new table, like this:

```
"SELECT DISTINCT"
              + "new com.abc.dc.entity.market.LaptopData(m.id, m.segmentGroup, "
              + "m.segmentName, m.category, "
              + "m.make, m.model, m.modelYear) "
              + "FROM someNewTable m"
              + "WHERE m.profileCode = :profileCode ";
```

This way you don't have to do join and ordering every time you execute your query, but only once a day when you generate new table. Ofcourse with this approach to see data updates you'll have to wait until new table is recreated.

Also, you can create indexes on fields you are using in **where** clause.

Comment: But here I don't find any time delay in retrieving data. But I guess the time increases due to object creation. I am not sure what exactly happens behind the screen with JPQL constructor usage. But its sounds like for each fetched row objects are created immediately. Is there any work around to speed up object creation?

Comment: Have you tested it? Do you have any profiler output? You can't workaround object creation, and it is very fast in java. I think most performance heavy operation it this case is **Order by** statement.

Comment: Yeah that's right. The problem is not with the object creation. Even when I use native query to fetch it is taking long time.